# are there different ways how to install a cloudera hadoop packages?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

can I only install packages via RPM? (RedHat Package Management)
Im using Cloudera and I heard a couple times about CDH Parcel Services but im not sure, if i can do that with this too? or is there another mechanism?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Debian or Ubuntu, then you'd use DEB packages, not RPM.

Parcels should work

So would compiling code from source.

Just because you're running Cloudera doesn't make the system any less of a regular Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

Parcels is Cloudera's way of installing their distribution.  You install Cloudera Manager, and it will install all of the components using parcels (although I think you have a choice).  This is done through a GUI (or API).  This is probably the easiest way to go about it.

If you are just learning, the Quick Start VM is not a bad way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I have done installation of Cloudera using Parcels and it is easier than package installation. Parcels are quite conveniently picked up by Cloudera Manager for installation purposes. Almost everything is ready once parcel installation is done.